# Kivy: Touch the label to check the checkbox

Tags: python, checkbox, kivy

I am trying to make an aap for MCQ's. Here i want a function, if anyone even click on the label corresponding to a checkbox, that check box must also be checked.. Is it possible in Kivy? Because Kivy doesn't provide any text association with checkbox directly.

Here is a portion of kv.

```
<MCQCheckBox@CheckBox>:
    color:0,0,0,1
    size_hint: 0.15, 1
    group: 'opts'

<MCQLabel@Label>:
    text_size: self.size
    valign: 'center'
    font_size: '13sp'
    color: 0,0,0,1

<MCQsGUI>:
   BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        size_hint: 0.95, 0.7
        spacing: 2
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}

    MCQBoxLayout:
        MCQCheckBox:
        MCQLabel:
            text:"option 1"
    MCQBoxLayout:
        MCQCheckBox:
        MCQLabel:
            text:"option 2"
    MCQBoxLayout:
        MCQCheckBox:
        MCQLabel:
            text:"option 3"
    MCQBoxLayout:
        MCQCheckBox:
        MCQLabel:
            text:"option 4"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using only kv languaje and dynamic classes:

- To allow the label to behave like a button, you just have to make  `MCQLabel` inherit from `Label` and `ButtonBehavior` classes.
- To keep the group's own behavior you can call the `_do_press ()` method of the [`ToggleButton`](https://kivy.org/docs/_modules/kivy/uix/behaviors/togglebutton.html) class (CheckBox inherits from it) when the asociated label is pressed.

**test.kv:**

```
<MCQCheckBox@CheckBox>:
    color: 0, 0, 0, 1
    size_hint: 0.15, 1


<MCQLabel@ButtonBehavior+Label>:
    text_size: self.size
    valign: 'center'
    font_size: '13sp'
    color: 0, 0, 0, 1


<MCQLabelCheckBox@BoxLayout>:
    text: ''
    group: ''

    MCQCheckBox:
        id: cb
        group: root.group

    MCQLabel:
        on_press: cb._do_press()
        text: root.text


<MCQsGUI>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    MCQLabelCheckBox:
        text:"option 1"
        group: 'opts'

    MCQLabelCheckBox:
        text:"option 2"
        group: 'opts'

    MCQLabelCheckBox:
        text:"option 3"
        group: 'opts'

    MCQLabelCheckBox:
        text:"option 4"
        group: 'opts'
```

**main.py:**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class MCQsGUI(BoxLayout):
    pass


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MCQsGUI()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

[image]

Comment: Nice.. Working like charm with a  very simple code.. Thank You so much.

Comment: In order to get the active state of the checkbox so it can be used in a program you need to add     active: cb.active underneath text: '' and group: '' in the MCQLabelCheckbox widget

Comment: I believe instead of `group: ''` it should be `group: None`, b/c otherwise multiple "MCQLabelCheckbox"s will always be in a group and only one of them can be checked.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a direct/'built-in' way to do that. But here is an improvised example without using `main.kv` file.

When you create a `CheckBox` and a `Label` object, you can manually connect the `CheckBox` pressing this way  :

```
import kivy
from kivy.uix.checkbox import CheckBox
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

class Answer(Label):
    def __init__(self, text, associate):
        Label.__init__(self);
        self.text = text;
        self.associate = associate;
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        Label.on_touch_down(self, touch);
        if self.collide_point(touch.pos[0], touch.pos[1]):
            self.associate.active =  not self.associate.active;

class Page(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        GridLayout.__init__(self, rows = 2, cols = 2);
        self.check = [CheckBox(), CheckBox()];
        self.ans = [Answer(text = 'Choice 1', associate = self.check[0]),\
                    Answer(text = 'Choice 2', associate = self.check[1])];
        for i in self.ans:
            self.add_widget(i);
        for i in self.check:
            self.add_widget(i);

class Example(App):
    def build(self):
        return Page()
```

So every time you press the `Label`, it will do : `self.associate.active = not self.associate.active` which works as the switch for the corresponding `CheckBox`.

*This is only one way, you can improvise or even find a better way. Is this okay?

Comment: Bro thank you so much, very very nice.. Can you show an example with a `page.kv` , as I am a beginner to Kivy.