# How To Replace Kivy Widgets On Callback?

Tags: python, oop, widget, kivy

I'm new to Python and Kivy, and I'm trying to create multipage display of letters of the braille alphabet, with the corresponding braille's letter picture present in every page. I really want to learn more about creating Kivy desktop apps. I really hope you can help me. What I'm trying to do is have a page look like this:[image: As]

I know how images and buttons are placed and customized in terms of size and position in the KV file. However what I need to learn is how `add_widget()` and `clear_widget()` will factor in this. I have read the Kivy docs but they barely explain how I could achieve what I need. What I thought of doing is using the `from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen` feature, and then just create 26 screens and route them via on_click in the kv file. But that's tedious and too manual. Here's my code so far:

```
class LetterAScreen(Screen):
    pass

class LetterBScreen(Screen):
    pass

class LetterCScreen(Screen):
    pass

class LetterDScreen(Screen):
    pass

class LetterEScreen(Screen):
    pass

class LetterFScreen(Screen):
    pass

class LetterGScreen(Screen):
    pass

 #.... so and so until Letter Z




sm = ScreenManager(transition=SwapTransition())

#LearnScreen - Alphabet
sm.add_widget(LetterAScreen(name='lettera'))
sm.add_widget(LetterBScreen(name='letterb'))
sm.add_widget(LetterCScreen(name='letterc'))
sm.add_widget(LetterDScreen(name='letterd'))
sm.add_widget(LetterEScreen(name='lettere'))

sm.add_widget(LetterFScreen(name='letterf'))
sm.add_widget(LetterGScreen(name='letterg'))
sm.add_widget(LetterHScreen(name='letterh'))
sm.add_widget(LetterIScreen(name='letteri'))
sm.add_widget(LetterJScreen(name='letterj'))
sm.add_widget(LetterKScreen(name='letterk'))
sm.add_widget(LetterLScreen(name='letterl'))

sm.add_widget(LetterMScreen(name='letterm'))
sm.add_widget(LetterNScreen(name='lettern'))
sm.add_widget(LetterOScreen(name='lettero'))
sm.add_widget(LetterPScreen(name='letterp'))
sm.add_widget(LetterQScreen(name='letterq'))
sm.add_widget(LetterRScreen(name='letterr'))

sm.add_widget(LetterSScreen(name='letters'))
sm.add_widget(LetterTScreen(name='lettert'))
sm.add_widget(LetterUScreen(name='letteru'))
sm.add_widget(LetterVScreen(name='letterv'))
sm.add_widget(LetterWScreen(name='letterw'))
sm.add_widget(LetterXScreen(name='letterx'))
sm.add_widget(LetterYScreen(name='lettery'))
sm.add_widget(LetterZScreen(name='letterz'))
```

I haven't gotten around the kv file because i'm clueless how this will pan out. What I need to do is create widgets or a function that will swap out the images of the current letter and display those of the next or previous ones when the next/button is clicked, without having to switch screens every single time. I'm really unfamiliar with how functions work in Kivy and Python. I hope you could help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution to your problem. I'll leave it to you to modify and make it look and work exactly how you want :)

Learning the kv language is INCREDIBLY helpful, easy, and it can be picked up quite quickly.

`main.py`

```
from kivy.app import App

class MainApp(App):
    alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

    def next_letter(self):
        # Get a reference to the widget that shows the letters
        # self.root refers to the root widget of the kv file -- in this case,
        # the GridLayout
        current_letter_widget = self.root.ids['the_letter_label']
        # Get the letter currently shown
        current_letter = current_letter_widget.text
        # Find the next letter in the alphabet
        next_letter_index = self.alphabet.find(current_letter) + 1
        next_letter = self.alphabet[next_letter_index]

        # Set the new letter in the widget that shows the letters
        current_letter_widget.text = next_letter

MainApp().run()
```

`main.kv`

```
GridLayout: # This is the `root` widget of the main app class
    cols: 1
    Label:
        text: "g"
        id: the_letter_label # Setting an id for a widget lets you refer to it later
    Button:
        text: "Previous"
    Button:
        text: "Next"
        on_release:
            # the keyword `app` references the main app class, so we can call
            # the `next_letter` function
            app.next_letter()
```

I'm happy to address specific questions if you have them.

Comment: thank you for the help! it clarified some things. I have a few questions. what is the purpose of the alphabet variable? Also, if I have multiple widgets per letter/page, does that mean I have to individually assign ids to them and call them one by one, or could I assign some sort of collective id in the kv that can contain multiple items such as labels and image etc and call it instead. a newbie sorry for being slow.

Comment: 1) The alphabet variable is just so I could know which letter in the alphabet came next when clicking the button that should display the next letter. 2) Generally I have ids for each widget. You can create a "collective item" as you call it - an example (not the main point of the question) can be seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48438074/kivy-touch-the-label-to-check-the-checkbox/48443383 The "collective item" would be the MCQLabelCheckBox in that example, and setting the `text` field I believe will change the text in the MCQLabel which has `text: root.text`