# How To Switch Between Kivy Layouts On Calllback?

Tags: android, python, oop, widget, kivy

I'm a beginner in Kivy and Python and I'm trying to create a simple alphabet app for practice. It should something look like this.[image: Simple alphabet app that should transfer between layouts when the next/prev button is pushed]

I want to create a simple alphabet app that should switch between layouts when the next/prev button is pushed.

What I tried to do is put the images in individual floatlayouts per letter of the alphabet, as to avoid having to use screenmanager and create/link 26 screens. I'm trying to just switch out the images by switching the FloatLayouts.

I asked the question previously [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55537731/how-to-replace-kivy-widgets-on-callback/55542348#55542348), and so far this is what I've got.

```
import kivy
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


class LearnAlphabetScreen(Screen):
    alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

    def next_letter(self):
        # Get a reference to the widget that shows the letters
        # self.root refers to the root widget of the kv file -- in this case,
        # the GridLayout
        current_letter_widget = self.root.ids['a']
        # Get the letter currently shown
        current_letter = current_letter_widget.text
        # Find the next letter in the alphabet
        next_letter_index = self.alphabet.find(current_letter) + 1
        next_letter = self.alphabet[next_letter_index]

        # Set the new letter in the widget that shows the letters
        current_letter_widget.text = next_letter

    def prev_letter(self):
        current_letter_widget = self.root.ids['a']
        # Get the letter currently shown
        current_letter = current_letter_widget.text
        # Find the next letter in the alphabet
        prev_letter_index = self.alphabet.find(current_letter) - 1
        prev_letter = self.alphabet[prev_letter_index]

        # Set the new letter in the widget that shows the letters
        current_letter_widget.text = prev_letter



Builder.load_string("""

<NextButton@Button>
    font_size: 32
    color: 1, 1, 1, 1
    size: 150, 50
    backgroundcolor: .88, .88, .88, 1
    size_hint: .4, .3
    pos: -5, 440


<PrevButton@Button>
    font_size: 32
    color: 1, 1, 1, 1
    size: 150, 50
    backgroundcolor: .88, .88, .88, 1
    size_hint: .4, .3
    pos: -5, 270


<LearnAlphabetScreen>:
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'bgpics/blackboard.png'

    FloatLayout:
    id:layouta
        Label:
            id:a
            text: "A"
            pos: -5, 210
            font_size: '40sp'

    FloatLayout:
    id:layoutb
        Label:
            id:b
            text: "B"
            pos: -5, 210
            font_size: '40sp'

    FloatLayout:
    id:layoutc
        Label:
            id:c
            text: "C"
            pos: -5, 210
            font_size: '40sp'

    NextButton:
        text: "Previous"
        on_release:
            screen.prev_letter()
    PrevButton:
        text: "Next"
        on_release:
            screen.next_letter()



""")



LA=LearnAlphabetScreen()  
class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return LA





if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()*
```

I'm clueless as to how I can execute what I plan. Each letter of the alphabet will be represented by a picture or text label, then they will be contained in individual FloatLayouts (I need them to be in separate FloatLayouts in order for me to be able to learn how to manipulate multiple contents in the future through layout switching). How do I refer to the id of the FloatLayout and make it switch layouts through the next/previous buttons?

I know there's something missing in my functions and kv file but I can't find it. I hope you can help me I really want to learn more about Python and Kivy. Thank you very much.

Comment: you can just change the image source file

Answer (score 0):

If it were a label you could potentially create a function which holds and loops the alphabet and then feed that into the input for a label.

Or.. just use different imgs A-Z and cycle through them (as @el3ien) mentioned.

Edit: 
Don't know if that's what you wanted but here are some functions that would achieve something close to that.

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

Alphabet = ascii_lowercase
i = -1

def next():
    global i
    if i<27:
        i = i + 1
    print(Alphabet[i])
next()

def previous():
    global i
    if i<27:
        i = i - 1
    print(Alphabet[i])
previous()
```

use these `on_release:` for your buttons. Make sure your running `i` is global. The rest of it would just be binding the variable to the label.